# How to set multiple cell properties using Office Js?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am trying to set cell value and properties for each cell in the selected range by using `Excel.Range.setCellProperties()` but I get an error in the console and the properties are not loaded in the spreadsheet.

This is the error I get in the console, but my cell's properties array seems to be correct.
[image]

I have previously extracted cell values from a range and stored them in a 2 dimensional string array: `cellValues`.

Here's an example of what `cellValues` contains

[image]

The cell properties to set have also been previously extracted from a range and stored in a 2 dimensional array, named `cellStyles`. This is what it contains:

[image]

Also, this is my code for setting the cell properties:

```js
Excel.run(async function(ctx) {
  OfficeExtension.config.extendedErrorLogging = true;
  const activeRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();

  activeRange.values = cellValues;
  await ctx.sync();

  // This is where the error happens
  activeRange.setCellProperties(cellStyles);

  await ctx.sync();
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error);
  if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
  }
});
```

**Note**: To give you a broader context of what I am doing, I am exporting the cell values and format properties of the selected range in Excel and then I want to be able to "import" these values and cell properties back into Excel.

**Update:**
This is the function I am using to export the content from Excel:

```js
async function exportExcelRange() {
  let res = await Excel.run(async function(ctx) {
    const range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();

    let cellPropsArray = range.getCellProperties({
      format: {
        autoIndent: true,
        borders: {
          color: true,
          weight: true,
          style: true,
          tintAndShade: true
        },
        fill: {
          color: true,
          patternColor: true,
          pattern: true,
          patternTintAndShade: true,
          tintAndShade: true
        },
        font: {
          bold: true,
          color: true,
          italic: true,
          name: true,
          size: true,
          strikethrough: true,
          subscript: true,
          superscript: true,
          tintAndShade: true,
          underline: true
        },
        horizontalAlignment: true,
        indentLevel: true,
        protection: true,
        readingOrder: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        textOrientation: true,
        useStandardHeight: true,
        useStandardWidth: true,
        verticalAlignment: true,
        wrapText: true
      },
      style: true,
      hyperlink: false
    });

    await ctx.sync();
    return cellPropsArray.value;
  }).catch(err => console.error(err));

  const nbCol = res[0].length;
  const nbRow = res.length;
  for (let row = 0; row < nbRow; row++) {
    for (let column = 0; column < nbCol; column++) {
      const cell = res[row][column];

      const newProps = {
        format: {
          autoIndent: cell.format.autoIndent,
          fill: {
            color: cell.format.fill.color,
            patternColor: cell.format.fill.patternColor,
            pattern: cell.format.fill.pattern,
            patternTintAndShade: cell.format.fill.patternTintAndShade,
            tintAndShade: cell.format.fill.tintAndShade
          },
          font: {
            bold: cell.format.font.bold,
            color: cell.format.font.color,
            italic: cell.format.font.italic,
            name: cell.format.font.name,
            size: cell.format.font.size,
            strikethrough: cell.format.font.strikethrough,
            subscript: cell.format.font.subscript,
            superscript: cell.format.font.superscript,
            tintAndShade: cell.format.font.tintAndShade,
            underline: cell.format.font.underline
          },
          horizontalAlignment: cell.format.horizontalAlignment,
          indentLevel: cell.format.indentLevel,
          readingOrder: cell.format.readingOrder,
          shrinkToFit: cell.format.shrinkToFit,
          textOrientation: cell.format.textOrientation,
          useStandardHeight: cell.format.useStandardHeight,
          useStandardWidth: cell.format.useStandardWidth,
          verticalAlignment: cell.format.verticalAlignment,
          wrapText: cell.format.wrapText
        },
        style: cell.style
      };

      res[row][column] = newProps;
    }
  }
  console.log(res);

  return JSON.stringify(res);
}
```

The content is saved as a JSON string which is then sent to my app's backend for storage. The `copyFrom()` function is essentially what I am trying to do, but with the JSON string that was saved earlier.

Comment: Would you please share the code for exporting the cell format properties? I would like to repro this issue in my side, it would be great if you could share me the gist to repro this issue. thanks

Comment: @RaymondLu I've updated my question with the needed code, unfortunately I can't share the whole project directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter in `setCellProperties` and `getCellProperties` are different.
they are 2 different class `SettableCellProperties` and `CellPropertiesLoadOptions`, so the logic for exporting cell format properties and convert to settableCellProperties is key for your scenario.

But, if you want to just copy the format from the range, I would suggest you could try to use [range.copyFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#copyfrom-sourcerange--copytype--skipblanks--transpose-) API, there is a `copyFromType` option, which allow to copy the format only.

[image]